# Find Numeric code string in a SELECT mysql statement with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, numeric

I save the single quote in my utf8 mysql database with `&#39;` .

now I just want to select all rows that include a `&#39;` in the name column. So I do:

```
SELECT * WHERE name LIKE "%&#39;%"
```

but this will give me an empty result. if I do

```
 SELECT * WHERE name LIKE "%&#%"
```

for example its working great.
What I am doing wrong? I want to search for the complete string `&#39;`.

Comment: the real question why did you HTML Entity encode that [apostrof](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm) when you use utf8 encoding..

Comment: Could you show us what the data looks like in the database?

Comment: `LIKE '%&#39;%'` works fine to find values that have `&#39;` in them; if you are not finding anything with that, then most likely your data does _not_ contain `&#39;` in the first place.

Comment: @hillcode did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of your query:

[https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ci63XiAPbKLaz7bRksJ4gW/1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ci63XiAPbKLaz7bRksJ4gW/2)

The problem may depend on something else, e.g. how the `'` is stored in the database.

May be the case that the `'` is inserted as is, so try this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE name LIKE "%'%";
```

In the same [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ci63XiAPbKLaz7bRksJ4gW/2) you can try this.

You can perform the search for both cases in the same query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (name LIKE "%&#39;%" OR name LIKE "%'%");
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `testone` WHERE `val` LIKE '&#39'

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlJC3.png)

[From Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmitv.png)

Comment: nope that is not doing the job ... the % is missing and the result is empty because the single quote is in the different name values